# How to get from Dictionary<char, Tuple <int, char>> int value for specific key?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries in the first case I used Tuple for key values and it works fine like this

```
Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int> pairPoints = new Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int>();
foreach (var items in this.pairPoints)
   Console.WriteLine(items.Key.Item1);
```

but in the second case, I want to get a value which is also in Tuple {int,char} however I can't find something like **result.Values.Item1**

```
Dictionary<char, Tuple <int, char>> result = new Dictionary<char, Tuple<int, char>>();
if(distance < result.Values.Item1) {//do my things}
```

Is it possible to write it something like this or do I have to use a different array method?

Comment: unclear question, what is your requirement finally ?

Comment: Are you trying to check if there is one value in the dictionary greater than the distance ? You're code doesn't work because you have a collection and not a single element !

Comment: yes my question is how to get value int from that tuple(int,char) as dictionary value

Comment: Well try this:  `if(result.Values.Any(t => t.Item1 > distance))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.Values` is a *collection* of `Tuple<int, char>`
You can access a single item in the collection by the dictionary key:

```
result[someChar].Item1
```

Or you can loop though all the values as follows:

```
foreach(var tuple in result.Values)
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you have multiple ways to do this. But you need to understand first that `result.Values` is a collection and not a single value, that's why you can't access `result.Values.Item1`.

Check if any result matches:

```
if(result.Values.Any(t => t.Item1 > distance))
{

}
```

Or Loop through results that match

```
foreach(var item in result.Values.Where(t => t.Item1 > distance))
{
  // use item.Item1 and item.Item2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this in wrong way. You have to use `Value` not `Values`

Correct way:

```
Dictionary<char, Tuple <int, char>> result = new Dictionary<char, Tuple<int, char>>();
    foreach (var items in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items.Value.Item1);
        Console.WriteLine(items.Value.Item2);
    }
```